# SQL unable to insert data after create trigger

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables with the following names:

- `product`
- `order_line`
- `invoice`

I want to create a trigger that whenever a new `order_line` row is inserted, the ordered numbers (specified in `order_line`) will reflect in my product table.

Below is the trigger that I have written:

```sql
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER update_on_the_way_stockcount
AFTER INSERT ON order_line
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF invoice.product_status='Pending' THEN
        UPDATE PRODUCT
            SET on_the_way_stockcount = (SELECT order_qty FROM order_line WHERE product.product_number = order_line.product_number);
        END IF;
    END //
```

However now I am unable to insert new rows into the `order_line` table, how can I resolve this?

Comment: *`IF invoice.product_status='Pending' THEN`* What row of `invoice` table you want to refer to?

Comment: I want to refer to the product_status

Comment: I do not ask about column. I ask what row do you want to use this column value from?

Comment: sorry, I don't understand what do you mean. I want to check all the rows that is having 'pending' and update the quantity of ordered items into the product - on-the-way quantity

Comment: I mean that when you type `invoice.product_status` then you want to refer to single value from some row (one!! row) of this table. And I ask - WHAT row from all rows stored in  this table?

Comment: The trigger is invalid. The table specified in the action cannot be referenced (for reading or writing) within the trigger's handling.